# ASP.Net custom control which can be hosted and can be consumed by various websites/webapplications

Tags: asp.net, iframe, custom-controls

In classic asp or asp.net you could create custom controls which would reside in the solution e.g customer control which could be used for customer's billing address and shipping address.

What i am trying to achieve is creating a website/iframe which could be hosted as a website or something and then the client applications would use this as an iframe in their application. The reason i want to do this is to have one central location for any changes and avoiding the need to recompile and redeploy existing applications whenever there is a change in control.

Is this possible to do? what would be the design like? any links to articles or similar solutions is highly appreciated.

Is it advisable to create a default page with content of custom control and then force the users/client app to consume that page in a iframe?

Thanks.